# Cannot find CatalogManager.properties

Tags: java, xml, xmlcatalog

My servlet app uses XML catalogs.

First I used `org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver`. 
It finds its configuration file `CatalogManager.properties` under `WEB-INF/classes/`.

Then I tried the same thing with `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager`, the version which comes with the JDK.

It doesn’t work:

```
Cannot find CatalogManager.properties
```

The spec says that this file must be somewhere on the CLASSPATH, and I suppose it is.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should work, the code is the same, just repackaged:

```
  propertyFileURI = CatalogManager.class.getResource("/"+propertyFile);
  InputStream in =
    CatalogManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+propertyFile);
  if (in==null) {
    if (!ignoreMissingProperties) {
      System.err.println("Cannot find "+propertyFile);
      // there's no reason to give this warning more than once
      ignoreMissingProperties = true;
    }
    return;
  }
```

What to do? Try debugging, set the breakpoint und see why it does not work.

Why do you need `CatalogManager.properties` anyway? If you don't, you could disable the error message with the system property `xml.catalog.ignoreMissing`.

Comment: Please let me know where I can change this property.

Comment: We found it, the setting must be added to environment variable:
`JAVACMD_OPTS=-Dxml.catalog.ignoreMissing=true`