# How to resolve Cannot find CatalogManager.properties error

Tags: java, catalog, resolver

I am using org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver to set entityResolver.

```
Document outdoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element outevent = outdoc.createElement("docs");
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    
   /*factory.isValidating();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);*/
    
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setEntityResolver(new CatalogResolver());
```

I have a CatalogManager.properties file under the src folder. But when I build the applicaiton, I get a cannot find CatalogManager.properties error. What am I doing wrong? There is only one [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672674/cannot-find-catalogmanager-properties) here regarding the issue. It does not provide much information except asking the reader to turn off the catalog option. I want to use the catalogmanager property.

### IDE

netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I added the folder that contains the property file to the library folder. Since library folder is already part of the classpath, it works. Hopefully, that's the correct approach.